# C++ wxWidgets: Set Font After Widget Creation

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

So basically I found out that you can only set font before the widget creation or font won't change, but I need to change the font after element creation so how can I do it?

```
void MyMain::makeBtnPanel()
{
    btnPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    wxGridSizer* grid = new wxGridSizer(5, 4, 2, 2);

    // here is hidden code that is adding widgets to grid

    btnPanel->SetSizer(grid);
    sizer->Add(btnPanel, 5, wxEXPAND);
}


void MyMain::styleBtns()
{
    wxFont mainBtnFont(
        16,
        wxFONTFAMILY_DEFAULT,
        wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL,
        wxFONTWEIGHT_EXTRALIGHT
    );
    btnPanel->SetFont(mainBtnFont);
}
```

`styleBtns` function is not working but if I set font immediately after `btnPanel` creation (on 2nd line of `makeBtnPanel` function) font will be set.

class constructor:

```
MyMain::MyMain()
    : wxFrame(
        NULL,
        wxID_ANY,
        "Calculator",
        wxDefaultPosition,
        wxSize(322, 392)
    )
{
    sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    SetSizer(sizer);
    makeDisplayPanel();
    makeBtnPanel();
    styleBtns();
    setupMainFrame();
}
```

Comment: You're definitely supposed to be able to do that. What widgets are you talking about?

Comment: @MichaelChon, what do you mean? The best way to do it in your case is to change the font in constructor in the child class. Or you can try to compile widgets sample which has an appropriate menu

Comment: Do you call `Refresh()` on the control after setting a different font to it?

Comment: @Ripi2 I tried to use `Refresh()` on the control after setting a different font to it but font still not changing

Comment: @catalin I have this hierarchy: `wxPanel` -> `wxGridSizer` -> multiple `wxPanel` -> `wxBoxSizer` -> `wxStaticText`. I want to apply a font to the 1st  `wxPanel` so all `wxStaticText` widgets are inheriting it instead of iterating through every single `wxStaticText` and applying font to it.

Comment: @Igor "_The best way to do it in your case is to change the font in constructor in the child class. Or you can try to compile widgets sample which has an appropriate menu –_". I don't understand. Can you please explain it more.

Comment: Post some code, better late than never. Talking about an issue we can not see is just guessing.

Comment: @MichaelChon, try to compile and run the widgets sample and see if you can change the font there

Comment: @Ripi2 I edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, I'm so dumb. I couldn't change font because I was setting font to empty variables. I wrote `else if` instead of `if` and code didn't execute, it didn't set these variables.